# AngularJS - Hide/Show directive output based on expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm wanting to output some markup from a custom Directive, but only if the model contains some text.

I'm almost there, but I'm just not quite sure how to turn the template on/off when the model changes, and if this is even the most efficient way of doing it.

Here is the markup:

```
<div data-ng-controller="test">
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" id="search" maxlength="75" data-ng-model="keywords" />
</div>
<searched data-ng-model="keywords"></searched>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('searched', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            keywords: '=ngModel'
        },
        template: '<span><span class="field">You searched for:</span> {{ keywords }}</span> ',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('keywords', function(newVal, oldVal){
                if(newVal === null) {
                    // Output nothing!
                } else {
                    // Output Template as normal.
                }
            }, true);

        }
    };
});

app.controller("test", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.keywords = null;
}]);
```

And an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YPdV2/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want to do, the easiest way would be with an `ng-show`. Then you don't even need the `$watch` (or the link function for that matter)

```
app.directive('searched', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            keywords: '=ngModel'
        },
        template: '<span ng-show="keywords.length > 0"><span class="field">You searched for:</span> {{ keywords }}</span> '
    };
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YPdV2/3/)

Comment: Superb, thanks a lot for that. I knew I was over complicating it :)

Comment: On reflection, is a Directive even worth using for this? All I actually wanted to do is exactly what's now in the template. Should I just use what's in the template in the actual markup? I've tried it in  the markup and it does exactly what I want, so is a Directive overkill?

Comment: If you don't need to reuse the same markup anywhere else, then yes, the directive is probably overkill. The directive is handy when you don't want to repeat the same markup multiple places.

Comment: I am only using this in one place, so I'll ditch the Directive in this instance. Thanks again for your help, it's much appreciated.